# How to find the value of multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I have tried to get the value of multiple checkboxes like this:

```
for (const p of i.options){
        const x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        x.setAttribute("class", "checkboxClass");
        x.value = p;

        const y = document.createElement("LABEL");
        const t = document.createTextNode(p);
        y.appendChild(t);


        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.height = "5px";
        div.appendChild(x);
        div.appendChild(y);
        document.getElementById("checkbox").appendChild(div);

        window.data.appendChild(x);
        window.data.appendChild(y);
        window.data.appendChild(div);
      }

const sixthQuestion = document.querySelector('.checkboxClass:checked').value;
```

In `for (const p of i.options)` p is the text of each checkbox which is taken from a JSON file.

I seem to be getting the value of one checkbox. How can I get the value of multiple ones?

I am trying to avoid using `jQuery` unless its necessary to.

Comment: querySelector only returns the first match. You want querySelectorAll

Comment: @CharlesBamford I tried changing it to querySelectorAll, but I am getting an error that the value is undefined.

Comment: you must iterate through all the checkboxes in your selection

Comment: @ShawnPacarar Has it right. Here's an example fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/jv0tbkw8/

Comment: Got it working, cheers :)